# Cannot reset form in Angular 11

Tags: angular11

In my Angular component I have this `form` that has one text input and two buttons.

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="reset">
   <button type="button" (click)="myForm.reset();">Reset</button>
</form>
```

If I click the first button text is cleaned. If I click the second one nothing happens. How can reset form with Angular?

Browser's console doesn't show any irregularities. `FormsModule` is imported to my NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true}),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful for someone. I've found that adding `ngModel` and `name` makes it work.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
   <input name="item" ngModel>
   <button type="button" (click)="f.reset();">Reset</button>
</form>
```

It's time to learn in detail about Angular forms. This tutorial seems to be a good one https://angular.io/guide/forms